# performance between object.property and map.get(object)

Tags: javascript, performance, v8, ecmascript-6

In ECMAScript 6, I have two way to define a dictionary:

Traditional method (with `dictionary = Object.create(null)`):

- set property: `dictionary.key = value` or `dictionary[key] = value`
- get property: `dictionary.key` or `dictionary[key]`

Using Map (with `dictionary = new Map()`):

- set a reference: `dictionary.set(key, value)`
- get a reference: `dictionary.get(key)`

In V8, are they give the same performance?

Comment: You should decide on the semantics that you need, not on the performance.

Comment: But my question is really about performance, what is the better semantics?

Comment: Well, they have *different* semantics. Apart from objects being limited to string keys, you also need to consider prototype inheritance so `Object` instances are not the best idea, you'd use `Object.create(null)` if at all. But usually, you'll want to use a `Map` for a dictionary if it is available.

Comment: If you really care about performance, you should benchmark your real application. Microbenchmarks (like the ones given by Nat) are hardly representative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test it yourself with JSPerf at [here](https://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/24) and [here](http://jsperf.com/map-vs-object-property-access/9). It looks like the result is quite vary depending on V8 version.

Comment: Those tests deal with such a small dataset. I most interested in map.get performance when there are around 500,000 key/value pairs.

Answer (score -1):

In principle Maps() are meant as mutable key-value stores and are likely [not guaranteed] to be implemented as hash maps.

On the other hand javascript engines will try to derive object shapes (think of them as implicit class definitions for a particular type of object) based on where and how the object is created and give them a fixed layout with particular keys at fixed offsets relative to the object header. This works well (cache-friendlier than hashmaps) for a small, fixed set of keys.

If the javascript engine detects that the objects do not conform well to some particular shape they'll treat it more like a map instead.

So the general guidance would be: If you know the keys in advance and their number doesn't exceed a dozen or so and you could set their values to `null` up front you can use objects.

If you are dealing with hundreds of keys or dynamically generated keys then use `Map()`